# Can I give someone specific permission?

Tags: licensing, attribution

Suppose I have a product released under some CC license. Someone comes to me and says "can I please build off of your software without giving credit?". To this I say sure!

Do I need to write them a piece of paper with proof (ie: "I hereby give permission to allow ________ to use my software without credit")?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can and no you don't have to.

1. You're the owner. Since you own all the rights, you can of course allow them to use without attribution.
2. You shouldn't have to write anything. If someone complains to this other dev that they're not attributing, the other dev can just say they've got permission, and point the complainant back to you. You can just confirm that. Of course, it may be wise to have some publically visible record of this, so you don't have to constantly confirm it.